# Separating E-mail addresses from a text file using tsch

Tags: unix, email-validation, tcsh

I have a a text file which contains E-mail addresses surrounded by a lot of garbage.
I need to separate just the E-mail adresses, and write each address in a separate line (or separate between them with a comma).

the text file looks like that:

per@netvision.net אירית שנהב;רוני אשכול 99; מרכז האולפן 99; דפני אלפר; תים רון; (eina@gmail.com) אינה דגן 9303; (ori@gmail.com) אילן דור 9406; 9304 אורי

I think to "catch" all the words that start with [A-Z] and end with [A-Z] because all the garbage around is not letter in English ([A-Z]).

Can someone show me how to write this script?

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using [`grep -o`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep).  It's not precisely "in" tcsh, but you can use grep from any script.  The `-o` option causes grep to return  only the text matched by the regexp.

It looks as if your input file currently separates records using a semi-colon.  This is important, since `grep` reads things line-by-line.  So we will use `tr` to replace your record separators with newlines to ensure that `grep` sees each record.

```
ghoti@pc> cat strip_email 
#!/bin/tcsh

setenv inputfile emails.txt
setenv re_email '[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]_%=+-]*@([[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]-])+\.)+[[:alnum:]]{2,}'

tr ';' '\n' < $inputfile | grep -Eo "$re_email"

ghoti@pc> ./strip_email 
per@netvision.net
eina@gmail.com
ori@gmail.com
ghoti@pc>
```

You can adapt the regular expression to whatever suits you.  On a unix or linux system, you can check man pages: [`re_format(7)`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format) or [`regex(7)`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/7/regex/) for documentation.  The `[:alnum:]` piece is documented there, as well as [`isalnum`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isalnum).

Comment: +1 for `setenv re_email ....` , especially a mixed char-class using posix and indivual chars!.

Comment: @MinorBalulu - great stuff.  And a check-mark, perhaps?  (To the left of the answer.)